# Python/Django - HTTP authentication

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, http-authentication

I want to put basic HTTP authentication somewhere in my code if a certain condition is met. The condition is a request parameter. To simplify, let's say I want it in a Django view.

I know how to do it in PHP. This is the chunk of code which does exactly what I want:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['key']) && $_REQUEST['key'] === 'value') {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
}
```

I can put this chunk of code anywhere in my PHP script and when execution hits those lines, authentication will be requested. If authentication fails, script execution will stop and a 401 Unauthorized header will be sent with the specified message. This is what I want in Python/Django. Here is a chunk of code, help me fill it in:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.REQUEST.get('key') == 'value':
        # FILL ME IN
```

What I want:

- to be able to put this chunk in code anywhere in code and have it require authentication from user (let's assume request variable is available to me, a django.http.response.HttpResponse instance also, as response)
- to be able to specify the condition under which authentication will be requested (like the presence of a parameter in the request)
- to halt further execution if the user supplies invalid credentials and to return a 401 Unauthorized response
- for the solution to be portable (copy/paste the chunk of code elsewhere and authentication will be triggered there once execution gets to it)

What I DON'T want:

- to have authentication requirement hardcoded on a call of a function (with a decorator)
- to change any global settings of my web application
- to change anything else outside the part of code I want my authentication to trigger
- to need any additional packages installed for this to work
- to share credentials of this authentication with the standard authentication for CMS access already set up in the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    if request.REQUEST.get('key') == 'value':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            response = HttpResponse('Text to send if user hits Cancel button', status=401)
            response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="My Realm'
            return response
        ...
```

This will return a `401` status code, but requires you to provide your own content/template. If it is acceptable for you to return a `403` status code, you can use the built-in `PermissionDenied` exception that returns a 403 page based on your '403.html' template:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def some_view(request):
    if request.REQUEST.get('key') == 'value':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise PermissionDenied
        ...
```

**EDIT:**

To implement HTTP Basic Authentication, you have to set up your webserver (Apache, nginx, whatever you're using) to handle this. You should check your webserver's documentation on how to do this.

Django implements a `RemoteUserBackend` to allow users to login using basic authentication, but this uses the same user model as the normal `ModelBackend`, so these are not separate. Luckily, [the middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L21) and [the backend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L74) are quite simple. The webserver will deny any request with invalid credentials, so any time the `'REMOTE_USER'` header (or whatever header value you use) is set, the user is properly authenticated. This header will be available in `request.META`, so to check if a user is authenticated using Basic Authentication, you can use this code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    if request.REQUEST.get('key') == 'value':
        if request.META.get('REMOTE_USER', None):
            do_something()
        else:
            response = HttpResponse('Text to send if user hits Cancel button', status=401)
            response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="My Realm'
            return response
        ...
```

Comment: This seems on the right track, but there's one problem in my case with it, request.user is the user which is logged in Django's CMS and I don't want that. I would like this authentication to be completely separate from the one used in Django. If you're logged in one, that has nothing to do with the other. Basically I want to see the supplied username & password and check it on my own. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Thanks, by using your input (and this link to obtain authentication UN/PW: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1304/), I managed to do everything I want, have a possibility to request authentication anywhere in code and have it separate from other authentication methods already in use in the existing app. When I got the UN/PW, I just saved authentication information in the session. I integrated everything in my existing code and everything works like it should and it's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a mixin with django's class based views for this

```
class AuthenticationMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse('text, test, text', status=401)
        return super(AuthenticationMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You would then use this in a view as follows

```
class MyView(AuthenticationMixin, DetailView):
.
.
.
```

If there is a view that you don't want to use authentication on all you need to do is not sub-class the authentication mixin in the class declaration

```
class MyUnauthenticatedView(DetailView):
.
.
.
```

Comment: I don't know why you think this would work, but setting a local variable in the `__init__` method won't do anything.

Comment: It was because I'd forgotten to add the return statement. I also realised the init method was not the correct place to do this so I've corrected that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I already am using class-based views, I just didn't know how to send an authentication request in a response and how to read provided credentials so I can authenticate them. I managed to do all that in the end.